# Why does Pandas df.mode() return a zero before the actual modal value?

Tags: pandas, mode

When I run df.mode() on the below dataframe I get a leading zero before the expected output.  Why is that?

```
df

sample       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
zone run                                                          
2    5      14   12  22  23  24  22  23  22  23  23 

print(df.iloc[:,3:10].mode(axis=1)))
```

gives

```
           0
zone run    
2    5    23
```

expecting

```
zone run    
2    5    23
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html)

> Return the mode**(s)** of the dataset. **Always returns Series** even if only one value is returned.

So that's how it is by design. A Series **must** have an index and it will start counting from 0. This ensures that the return type is stable regardless of whether there is only a single mode or multiple values tied for the mode.

So if you take a slice where values are tied for the mode, your return is a Series where the numbers 0, ...N are indicators for the N values tied for the mode (modal values in sorted order).

```
df.iloc[:, 4:7]
#sample     5   6   7
#zone run            
#2    5    24  22  23


df.iloc[:,4:7].mode(axis=1)
#           0   1   2       # <- 3 values tied for mode so 3 labels
#zone run            
#2    5    22  23  24
```

Comment: Makes sense with respect to the multiple modes.  But why then does a function like df_mode.loc[zone=2,run=5] return 0 23 instead of simply returning the value of 23?

Comment: @ghowe because `df_mode` is a **DataFrame**. It may only have a single column, but it's still a DataFrame, which is 2D. The return of `DataFrame.loc` is a Series (so long as the index is not duplicated) where the indices are the DataFrame columns (in that case the single 0 column becomes the single 0 index). On the other hand since Series are 1D `Series.loc` returns a value (so long as the index is not duplicated)

Answer (score 0):

My thinking is, `df.mode` returns a dataframe. By default, dataframes if no column values are given allocates indices as column names. In this case,`0` is allocated because that is how pandas/python begins count.
Because it is a dataframe, the only way to change the column name which in this case is an index is to apply the `.rename(columnn)` method. Hence, to get what you need you will have to;

```
df1.iloc[:,3:10].agg('mode', axis=1).reset_index().rename(columns={0:''})

   zone run 
0   2    5   23
```